# how can i make a server using openssl implementing a tor type protocol? (a server is a public key or certificate)

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tor

i want to create a server with openssl from which it implements a tor protocol how can i do this? thanks

I dont have any idea how can do this and search in google but not  found nothing interesting